# PHP $_POST not being passed through from textarea

Tags: php, post, textarea

I have the following script to ask for a password and then ask the user if they want to edit a page. Click on a page opens it up in the '`<textarea>`', the save button should then send the content of the text area to the script again for writing. (I am aware that this isn't the safest way of authenticating, if there is any way of doing this without SQL I'd like to hear it.)

The problem is that the content of the text area isn't being passed through to the updateFile() function.

```
<?
session_start();
$pass = 'generic_password';
$login ='<form action="?page=admin" method="post">
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>'; 
function updateFile($file){
    $area=$_POST['area'];
    $fd=fopen($file,"w");
    fwrite($fd,$area);
    fclose($fd);
    echo $file.' has been saved';
    }
if (!isset($_POST['pass']) && $_SESSION['authed'] == false){
    echo $login;  
    $_SESSION['authed'] = false;
    }
elseif ($_POST['pass'] == $pass || $_SESSION['authed'] == true){
    $_SESSION['authed'] = true;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        updateFile($_POST['file']);
    }

    echo "Select a page to edit<br/>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach (glob("{*.html,*.css}",GLOB_BRACE) as $x){
        echo "<li> <a href=\"?page=admin&edit=$x\">$x </a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="nicEdit.js"></script> 
              <script type="text/javascript"> 
                bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
              </script> ';
        echo '<form method="post" action="?page=admin">You are editing: <a name="file">'.$_GET['edit'].'</a> <textarea name="area" style="width:920px;">';
        include $_GET['edit'];
        echo '</textarea>
              <input name="submit" value="Save" type="submit" />
              </form>';
    }
}
else
    echo "something went wrong";

?>
```

Comment: what says var_dump($_POST)? The index 'area'  set but blank or not set?

Comment: Your habit of putting closing curly bracket at the same level with nested block is damn awful

Comment: @Shrapnel, how do you propose I arrange the braces?

Comment: What's the use of sessions in this code?

Comment: **THE SAME LEVEL AS OPENING BLOCK**.

Comment: First of all separate authentication from the rest. Make it separate script and make it work. Then make your file saving script. Make it work. Separately. Then add only `if (!empty($_SESSION['authed']))` check to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="submit" value="Save" type="submit" />
```

the above never converted to `$_POST['submit']`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is passed in `updateFile` function. I doubt how you are able to open the file

There is `<a>` element with the name `file` Which will not available in `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    updateFile($_POST['file']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably You're wrong over here:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  updateFile($_POST['file']);
}
```

Here you're taking away an input file. where in your form there does not any such field exist, only an anchor tag is there with such name and $_POST can not take away the data inside an anchor tag. So its better to keep there a field for file name seperately like,

Hope this helps.